# charge image accord test of a row

Tags: jquery

i have a question:
i have a table that charge a Webservice, the Webservice use 4 status (Proposed, Confirmed. In progress and Cancelled), this values are charged into a row of a table.

i want to a script that check this column and if say cancelled put a image of a red equis, how can i do that?

i want to use jquery and work with a DOM.

i thing that maybe with a script that reed the ID of the column and if the row have "Cancelled" change the text and add a image

Regards Guys

Comment: You don't need an ID (probably) you need row with specified text. However, without seeing HTML, it is hard to say more.... If you can setup some kind of demo, it would be great...

Comment: you'r right, i use a class with a background image in the class :D and works! Thanks!